# Is Flash CS5.5 required for iOS deploying

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, flash-cs5

I'm looking into an iOS app deploying (need to help a friend with his iOS-designated game made in Flash), and the question is, will Flash Professional CS5 be enough for successful submission to the AppStore? Is there some lack of iOS related functionality, comparing to Flash CS5.5?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Flash CS5.5 for this. Maybe it is also possible with FlashBuilder 4.5. But I don´t now your project setup.

If the game is developed and compiled with Flash then there is no other choice as to use CS5.5 or CS6.

If you in the beginning of development you could use Flash Builder and create an AS3 project. I prefer the last option but I would use intelliJ IDEA as the development environment.

Comment: In Adobe Flash CS5 they have in Publish Settings an option for exporting to iOS devices. The question is, is it enough in most cases and the functionality of the app won't be affected, or is it better to upgrade to 5.5?